# How to prevent automatic assignment of values to missing data imported from SPSS

Tags: python, pandas, spss

Let's say I have an spss file named "ab.sav" which looks like this:

```
gender  value  value2

F       433    329
.        .     787
.        .      .
M       121     .
F       311    120
.        .     899
M       341     .
```

In spss (Variable View) I defined the labels of `gender` with the values `1` and `2` for `M` and `F` respectively.

When I load this in python using the following commands:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri  
>>> foreign=importr("foreign")
>>> data=foreign.read_spss("ab.sav", to_data_frame=True, use_value_labels=True)
>>> pandas2ri.activate()
>>> data2=pandas2ri.ri2py(data)
```

I get the following dataframe:

```
>>> data2

  gender   value   value2
0   F        433    329
1   M        NaN    787
2   M        NaN    NaN
3   M        121    NaN
4   F        311    120
5   M        NaN    899
6   M        341    NaN
```

So the missing values in the `gender` column for a given case are replaced by the subsequent known value of the subsequent case. Is there a simple way to prevent this?

When I change `use_value_labels` to `False` I get the expected result though:

```
>>> data2

  gender   value   value2
0   2        433   329
1   NaN      NaN   787
2   NaN      NaN   NaN
3   1        121   NaN
4   2        311   120
5   NaN      NaN   899
6   1        341   NaN
```

However I'd like to be able to use the labels instead of numeric values for `gender` as above. Ideally the output should be:

```
>>> data2

  gender   value    value2
0   F        433     329
1   NaN      NaN     787
2   NaN      NaN     NaN
3   M        121     NaN
4   F        311     120
5   NaN      NaN     899
6   M        341     NaN
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I updated my question. I'd like to keep the label information for each level of the factor gender, M and F in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data2` is a pandas DataFrame, and there's a 1-to-1 mapping between nulls in `value` and `gender`, you can do the following:

```
nulls = pandas.isnull(data2['value'])
data2.loc[nulls, 'gender'] = np.nan
```

And that turns it into:

```
  gender  value  value2
0      F    433     329
1    NaN    NaN     787
2    NaN    NaN     NaN
3      M    121     NaN
4      F    311     120
5    NaN    NaN     899
6      M    341     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that I have dozens of variables like "gender", so doing what you suggest for all those variables would take ages. I was looking for a way to prevent the automatic assignment of labels to missing values when I import the data into python. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Is there any reason to hold on to the rows that are all NaN?

Comment: Yes. I updated my example. Cases sometimes have NaN in some columns but not in others, so I'd like to keep all cases.